# How to measure the code obfuscation?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler, measurement

Say I have obfuscated a source code, how should I evaluate the obfuscation by quantitative measurement? My concern is that there are human and automatic adversaries. What is the best way to consider the effects from both sides. Any insights would be appreciated here :-)

Comment: Obfuscation - certainly when your code is javascript ran inside a browser - is irrelevant and only useful to reduce file size. You do not need to obfuscate code otherwise as you can always run it through a program to prettify it again if you insist. A human uses a computer for that, a computer just does it for itself if it needs to.

Comment: Thanks! The "prettify" program can never recover all the information. Thats why we need obfuscation. But some "prettify" can crack the obfuscation to a large extent. So I want to measure how good an obfuscation is.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish here? Apart from renaming variables etc you can easily analyse the flow of data and _all_ the information inside your app using a prettified version, so your obfuscation is pointless for two reasons: a developer determined to figure out how it works will be able to and a computer most certainly will, and everyone else simply wont care. If the code is crucial to not be read, you should not send it over and only process it in an environment where you have control.

Comment: The measurement how well something is obfuscated, no matter if it is compiled into machine-code, byte-code or just renaming variables, depends  on the tools that exists for code analysis and on the person reading the code, I learned to read and understand code even if the namings are not self-explaining, with code refactoring, you can clean up even a large code base really fast. But generally the _quality_ of obfuscation for a dynamic and not type-save language like js will always be bad.

Comment: Almost all JS obfuscators have a single goal, reducing file size. They're not about reducing readability (though it's often a side effect). What I mean by this is, they rename variables and remove unnecessary characters. They do not, however, in general, insert "nonsense" operations designed to trick a human into getting lost in the logic as things like that would increase file size, nor do they modify program flow. If your code is sensitive enough that you don't want users to have it, don't use JavaScript to write it. Use server-side technologies.

Comment: Another approach would be to compare each original to the obfuscation and by measuring the [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). But as other comments state, this doesn't necessarily mean that the obfuscation is "better".

Comment: What +dman2306 stated.  What are you trying to protect?  Is it is the intellical property? A password?  The Closure Compiler doesn't try to protect the code through obfuscation, it is trying to reduce code size.  Often it does this by reducing complexity (which in some case make you code easier to decipher)